# SwingNode with transparent content

Tags: java, swing, javafx, javafx-8

I'm trying to embed Swing content in a larger JavaFX application, however I can't get the embedded JPanel to have a transparent background. The JPanel only paints some of its area. I'd like the green to "show through", i.e. remove the light grey background in picture below.

[image: Swing node with background]

```
public class TransparentSwingNode extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
        pane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: green");
        final SwingNode swingNode = new SwingNode();
        BorderPane.setMargin(swingNode, new Insets(20));
        createAndSetSwingContent(swingNode);
        pane.setCenter(swingNode);
        // swingNode.setStyle("-fx-background-color: transparent"); // doesn't work

        stage.setScene(new Scene(pane, 240, 240));
        stage.show();
    }

    private void createAndSetSwingContent(final SwingNode swingNode) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JPanel panel = new DummyPanel();
                panel.setOpaque(false);
                // panel.setBackground(null); // doesn't work
                // panel.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0)); // Doesn't work
                swingNode.setContent(panel);
            }
        });
    }

    private class DummyPanel extends JPanel {
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.fillOval(getHeight() / 4, getHeight() / 4, getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I've tried

- various combinations of setOpaque(false), setBackground(null), etc.
- Setting the background of the SwingNode to transparent
- Lots of searching

Update

- We've found a workaround, see answer. However I'd still be interested in finding a better more stable way of doing this...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My colleague finally tracked something down. The system property `swing.jlf.contentPaneTransparent`, i.e. `-Dswing.jlf.contentPaneTransparent=true`

### Result

[image: Transparent background using system property]

I cannot find any official documentation on this apart from

- a mention in  [RT-37810 - Swing Nodes have serious rendering artifacts when first displayed on the primary Stage](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-37810)

> Also, we have an experimental undocumented option
>   ("swing.jlf.contentPaneTransparent") to switch on SwingNode's
>   transparency. That's to say that we probably shouldn't refuse
>   transparency support, unless this requires serious efforts.

- [JavaOne "Swing 2 JavaFX" Powerpoint](https://oracleus.activeevents.com/2013/connect/fileDownload/session/3B1A79EFDC437BA2A2FF3B475C42EF79/BOF4244_Northover.pptx)

Comment: Just to make it clearer: You can use this by adding to your code

`Properties props = System.getProperties();
props.setProperty("swing.jlf.contentPaneTransparent", "true");`

or by adding `-Dswing.jlf.contentPaneTransparent=true` to the Run parameters.